# Android - "IllegalStateException: Fragment Did Not Create a View" on Startup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

It appears that somehow somewhere I'm missing something, because after my app is minimized (not shut down), and then some of its memory is cleared, the app will crash upon resuming it. For instance, the crash is 100% reproducible by minimizing the app, opening up 8 other apps quickly, then switching to mine.

I already looked here for this question, but found nothing related (not replacing my XML-created Fragment, my super.onCreate is before setContentView, etc).

The exact error (line 2325 of FragmentManager.java) is:

```
if (fragment.mView == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + fname
                + " did not create a view.");
    }
```

Error:

```
01-17 13:32:34.902 16520-16520/com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp, PID: 16520
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp/com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.actMainPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                               at com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.actMainPage.onCreate(actMainPage.java:52)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.fragments.BottomNavFragment did not create a view.
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2325)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                               at com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.actMainPage.onCreate(actMainPage.java:52) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Fragment:

```
public class BottomNavFragment extends Fragment {

private static BottomNavFragment mInstance;

public static BottomNavFragment getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new BottomNavFragment();
        return mInstance;
    } else {
        return mInstance;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_bottom_nav, container, false);
}
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".actMainPage">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.fragments.BottomNavFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/frag_bottom_nav"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

frag_bottom_nav.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
tools:context="com.spielpark.steve.bernieapp.fragments.BottomNavFragment"
android:background="#147FD7"
android:weightSum="4"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:weightSum="4.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_public_white_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/issuesPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_note_white_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/organizePic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_people_white_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/connectPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map_white_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="3"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4.0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/issuesTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Issues"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/organizeTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Organize"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="switchPage"
        android:tag="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

..and lastly, the main activity. actMainPage.42 is setContentView();

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_page);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#147FD7")));
    mTitle = "News";
    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bernie_app_prefs", 0);
    adjustNavBarText(0);
}
```

Thanks so much for any help you're able to offer! Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: post frag_bottom_nav.xml

Comment: Any particular reason for the static reference and `getInstance()`?  I think that's what is causing your problems.

Comment: @krislarson it's just a pattern I've been using for all of my fragments -- probably unnecessary in this one considering that I don't ever replace it. I can try removing it, but the method and variable is never actually used. Here's where it's useful for me; https://github.com/SandersForPresident/BernieAppAndroid/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/com/spielpark/steve/bernieapp/actMainPage.java#L67-L113

Comment: Oh.  You talked about memory being cleared, so I thought it was a likely culprit.  My only other suggestions would be 1) Since it's in a `DrawerLayout` from the support library, make sure you are importing `Fragment` from the support library, and 2) try taking the fragment out of XML, add it programmatically and see if that makes a difference. Cheers